# My Ref is undefined when I try to hide a component in React

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm building an app in React with React-Bootstrap components (which includes the OverlayTrigger component).

I am getting an error on load when I try to call a function within the OverlayTrigger component. The `hide()` function exists inside the OverlayTrigger component and I've done something similar with it before (and it worked fine). I'm having a hard time debugging this.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined
    at React.createClass.closeOverlay (TaskStatusIcon.jsx:7)
```

And this is the actual code:

```
TaskStatusIcon = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
      task: React.PropTypes.object,
  },

  closeOverlay() {
    this.refs.overlayTrigger.hide();  // THIS IS THE PROBLEM
  },

  handlePopoverClick(status) {
    Actions.tasks.setStatus.bind(null, this.props.task, status);
    this.closeOverlay();
  },

  renderOverlay() {
    return (
      <Popover title="Mark as...">
        <div onClick={this.handlePopoverClick(TASK.INCOMPLETE)}>Incomplete</div>
        <div onClick={this.handlePopoverClick(TASK.IN_PROGRESS)}>In Progress</div>
        <div onClick={this.handlePopoverClick(TASK.DONE)}>Done</div>
      </Popover>
    );
  },

  render() {
    let imgSrc = "/icon1.jpg";
    return (
      <OverlayTrigger ref="overlayTrigger" trigger="click" rootClose placement="bottom" overlay={this.renderOverlay()}>
        <a href="#" style={{display:'inline-table'}}>
          <div>
            <img src={imgSrc} className='img-circle' />
          </div>
        </a>
      </OverlayTrigger>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: The issue is that you are calling the event handlers immediately instead passing a reference to them. You want `onClick={foo}`, not `onClick={foo()}`.

Comment: @FelixKling Ahh, I see. Indeed the problem goes away when I make it `{foo}` instead of `{foo()}`. But how do I pass in the specific information of what the user clicked then?

Comment: You could add that information as a `data-` attribute to the element and read it from `event.target`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked.